# rxjs.forkJoin ignore all success responses when one observable inside array fails, How to get info which observables were success?

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs, fork-join

I have dynamic array of `[]Observables`, and I need to call them before `finalize()` API will be called, because then it will automatically `lock` the whole Object in DB for any modifications.
Issue is that observables inside that array are for POST method.

Everything works fine when no error occurs during upload. But I have an issue what if one of the API call inside forkJoin failed, then I have no chance to got **success** responses ? I got array of responses only when all observables finish with no error, but when at least one failed, then I lost all **responses** which were success.

**Is there any other rxjs method for my usage? Or should it be handled somehow with `pipe/map`?** Array contains same API service, only difference are the `data and requestParams`.

**here is the code sample**

```
   ....

   const observables = [];
   // observables is filled in for-loop dynamically
   for(let file of this.obj.files){
     ...
       // when condition is ok
       const apiUpload = this.service.upload(file);
       observables.push(apiUpload)
   }

   forkJoin<any[]>(observables).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        console.log('responses ', res);
        // ready to finalize
        // this.finalize();
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
       // i am not able to find which API from array of observables are allready success 
      },
    });

....
```

It looks like forkJoin is mainly preferable for `GET` API services, which were just obtaining data, not storing data..
Any suggest how can I proceed?

I have in my mind another "hacky" that probably it is possible to catch the response of all CALLS via `Interceptor` but I do not know if it is a good solution ?

Comment: If one of the observables in the `fprkJoin` fails, the entire observable will fail.  I'm not aware of any workaround here, you can definitely use `catchError` to react to the failed call, but the observable itself will not complete.

Comment: You can make a separate call for each of your observables, which will prevent one failed call to affect the other calls. Not the prettiest, but it should work that way.

Comment: You mean call that one more time? but without that which will return error ? that is not a valid solution, because again call the same API which was allready success will throw another error, that the "file" allready exists in the database, so probably I need to find something similar to forkJoin, but where I am able to handle individually each of the response, and then if all those observables will finished then decide if all is fine and I am able to call `finalize()` or if error occurs then skip calling `finalize()` so for me it is very important to wait till all services will not be called

Comment: It's not meant to be a solution/answer (hence I posted a comment, not an answer). I'm not aware of a rxjs solution to your problem, which is why I proposed the alternative to make separate cslls for each of your observables inside of  `observables`.

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Are you storing files in memory, creating observables for them, and then once you have finished attempting to store them in the database? @MikeS. is correct that a separate call for each of your observables will work. Something like `mergeMap` will allow you to perform multiple API calls in parallel and you can handle each error individually.

Answer (score 2):

## Materialize errors in your observable

The short of it is that you can turn your errors into emissions that that they're not propagated into the operation of `forkJoin`. Of course, you'll still want a way to recover what was a regular emission and what was an error.

This process of converting notifications back and forth is called materializing and de-materializing. RxJS has a materialize operator, but you can create the wrapper yourself.

So here's how your example might look:

```ts
const observables = [];
// observables is filled in for-loop dynamically
for(let file of this.obj.files){
  ...
    // when condition is ok
    const apiUpload = this.service.upload(file).pipe(
      map(response => ({
        success: true,
        file,
        response
      })),
      catchError(error => of({
        success: false,
        file,
        response: error
      }))
    );
    observables.push(apiUpload)
}

forkJoin(observables).subscribe({
  next: (res) => {
    console.log('responses ', res);
    // ready to finalize
    // this.finalize();
  }
});
```

Because you've turned errors into `next` emissions, you'll see both error and successes in the array processed by `forkJoin`.

---

#### Aside: Same thing using materialize

```ts
const observables = [];
// observables is filled in for-loop dynamically
for(let file of this.obj.files){
  ...
    // when condition is ok
    const apiUpload = this.service.upload(file).pipe(
      materialize(),
      take(1), // ignore materialized `complete`
      map(notification => ({
        file, // remember which file was uploaded
        ...notification // kind: success 'N' or error 'E'
      }))
    );
    observables.push(apiUpload)
}

forkJoin(observables).subscribe({
  next: (res) => {
    console.log('responses ', res);
    // ready to finalize
    // this.finalize();
  }
});
```